# creating new object through python API is different from existing one

Tags: python

In the blender model, i have a white line which is based on plane. I used the code below to make a second one.

```
def createObjectWithName(name):
    obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
    mesh = obj.data
    new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)
    return new_obj

 createObjectWithName('spot1')
```

[image]

However, the new created one is so different from the existing one, I can't figure out why, can anyone help?

Comment: try apply transform(location. rotation and scale)

Comment: New object is working fine. It appears you are after a duplicate `new_obj = obj.copy()`  Otherwise as pointed out by  @ВладКиндюшов would need to set the transforms, `new_obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world`  as well as constraints and other object level props.

Comment: when i tried new_obj=obj.copy() or new_obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world, the new created object disappeared from the image.

Comment: @ВладКиндюшов you are right, that is the problem of scaling

Comment: if you need save a transform use how said @batFINGER

Comment: @batFINGER could you post the comment as a answer, i would accept this answer